# Fastest Way to filter Distance Between Two Lat/Long using geospatial in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, geospatial

I have 2 large files in both file i have the lat and long. i am trying to filter out all records that are within 500 meter.

I have follow the below step.

1.First I have joined with dataframe on the condition like abs(lat1-lat2) < 0.01 and abs(long1 - long2) < 0.01

`val joindf = df1.join(broadcast(df2),abs(df1.lat1-df2.lat2) < 0.01 && abs(df1.long1-df2.long2) < 0.01)` //will do the kind of crossjoin and return all rows within 5 km.

2.after that i have calculated the distance(basically call custum function that takes lat1,lat2,long1,long2 and its return distance in meter).

3.after that i have added the filter condition like distance <=500

But the above step works fine in small dataset but not working on Huge data. Its takes around 4 days in step 1.

Please help me out can we resolve this using geospatail. i have read the document but i am new in spark. please help me out.

The data frame sample like.

Dataframe 1

```
Tehsil  District    Type    Code    POP V_Lat   V_Long
Tulsipur    Balrampur   NON Census Village  0   0   27.594705   82.334491
Tulsipur    Balrampur   NON Census Village  0   0   27.605287   82.34746
Tulsipur    Balrampur   NON Census Village  0   0   27.573511   82.336592
Tulsipur    Balrampur   NON Census Village  0   0   27.582564   82.355718
Tulsipur    Balrampur   NON Census Village  0   0   27.57687    82.322748
Tulsipur    Balrampur   NON Census Village  0   0   27.583982   82.344223
Tulsipur    Balrampur   NON Census Village  0   0   27.577273   82.330141
Tulsipur    Balrampur   NON Census Village  0   0   27.569862   82.326575
Tulsipur    Balrampur   Village 173435  2702    27.584897   82.353102
Tulsipur    Balrampur   Village 173434  2552    27.592387   82.330867
Tulsipur    Balrampur   Village 173436  3506    27.5734 82.340243
Tulsipur    Balrampur   Village 173431  1693    27.599005   82.345086
Haidergarh  Bara Banki  NON Census Village  0   0   26.579465   81.461515
```

dataframe 2

```
UE  Purwa Dhanauti  Haidergarh  Bara Banki  NON Census Village  0   0   26.568228   81.471936
UE  Purwa Lachhmansingh Haidergarh  Bara Banki  NON Census Village  0   0   26.569711   81.478505
```